# Cannot checkout with TortoiseSVN using server DNS

Tags: svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn, xampp

I'm having a bit o trouble setting up a home SVN server in Windows XP. Following tutorials on the internet, I was able to make it work using XAMPP, and configuring WebDav for use with Subversion.

I have forwarded my 8280 port on my router, since my ISP blocks port 80. I've also created a no-ip host, since my IP is dynamic, and by typing it's URL in a browser, I'm able to see XAMPP's server page (I've set Apache to listen on this port as well). I'm using no-ip's "redirect port 80" option, forwarding it with port 8280.

I have created a repository in C:/svn, and I am also able to see the repository files if I type my no-ip URL followed by the repository path, as in "http://mysite.no-ip.org/svn". I have asked a friend to do the same from the internet and he was able to see the files too.

Also, I'm using TortoiseSVN as a client, and if I try to checkout my repository using my no-ip URL, I get the following error:

```
"Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://mysite.no-ip.org/svn'
OPTIONS of 'http://mysite.no-ip.org/svn': could no connect to server
('http://mysite.no-ip.org)"
```

However, if I try to checkout using "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8280/svn" (where the x's form my external IP) it works perfectly, even from the internet.

Is there any extra configuration needed in TortoiseSVN to make it work with DNS? What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When using svn over http apart from GET/PUT/etc it uses some less-common http methods like OPTIONS that is failing in your request. It easily can be that no-ip or somebody else blocks these requests, thus if you make a simple get to your `http://mysite.no-ip.org/svn` with your browser, you will see the list of the files, but TortoiseSVN will not be able to use that url. See also here: http://www.svnforum.org/threads/32996-Use-Tortoise-SVN-behind-a-firewall?p=88942&viewfull=1#post88942

Comment: Thanks for the reply MrTJ. Do you have any suggestion on how could I possibly find out who exactly is blocking this request ?

Comment: Hi, I would debug the http responses with a low-level http client. You can find one online at http://web-sniffer.net/ or a lot desktop as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put Try to make an OPTIONS request to your no-ip server and see what happens, maybe you get some error that will allow you to go forward.